# How to put div pictures in line with each other

Tags: html, css, button, hyperlink

### [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4oh3tejm/2/)

Im very new to HTML and CSS and my weakest points are positioning things. 
1)Each picture has its respective green button but my question is how do i put these pictures next to each other instead of on top of each other?

2) how would I code it so that if I hovered over the picture, the corresponding button would still change color up and allow me to click the picture to go to the link?

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<div id="chewning">
<img src="http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xap1/t51.2885-15/10518156_366963580136787_506416400_a.jpg" </img>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/maxxchewning">
<div id="EFGREEN">

    </div>
    </a>

<div id="CG">
<img src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0232/0959/products/575757_10152033748519359_1620549997_n_2.jpg?v=1398666646"></img>
</div>

<a href="https://www.youtube.com/user/Christianguzmanfitne">
    <div id="CGGreen">
</div></a>
</html>
```

### CSS

```
#chewning {
            display:inline-block;
            margin-right:1000px;
            margin-top:-40;
        }
        #EFGREEN {
            background-color:green;
            width:306px;
            height:100px;
            display:block;
        }

        #EFGREEN:hover{
            background-color:red;
        }

        a:{
            display:block;
        }
        #CG{
            float:right;
        }
        #CGGreen{
            background-color:green;
            width:414px;
            height:500px;
        }
        #CGGreen:hover{
            background-color:red;
        }
```

Comment: Your markup makes no sense.

Comment: Since your new to html and css it wouldn't be a bad thing to use Bootstrap 3.0 to help you understand how things in css should work based on what you want to do. http://www.http://getbootstrap.com/ just play with it for a while to understand it better

Comment: Your mock up speaks volume of how important it is that you start from the basics. Follow this link to learn the basics of HTML and CSS. http://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp

Comment: I would suggest heading to [CodeAcademy](http://www.codecademy.com/) and starting with the basics of HTML and CSS markup, rather than just delving in unprepared like you have.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in some comments, the markup and CSS of your demo
could be improved and there are plenty of online resources (won't recommend
any specific).
But as you have 2 specific questions - how to display both images next to
each other and how to change the link in a way that also the image is linked and the button is displayed in hover state (changes the background color) when the image is hovered - I'd just like to give an answer as well as maybe providing some information on how to improve your code.

In this adjusted [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/69ubpqfc/) I've kept but commented out your CSS and added the following new CSS instead:

```
.button {
  background-color:green;
  width:100%;
  height:100px;
}
.item {
  float:left;
}
.item:hover .button {
  background-color:red;
}
```

To display both images next to each other, I've wrapped both items (image and button)
in a div with the class `item`. These items float left, so they're displayed
next to each other. I've added the class `button` to both buttons so it's not
necessary to repeat styles based on the buttons' ids.
You've set the width of both buttons to the different widths of the images which
can be handled in a more dynamic approach by just setting the width of the
buttons to 100% - based on the image width the surrounding `item` container
will have the width of the image, and the div with the class `button` automatically 
has the same width (100% of the container).
I've moved the anchor tags that previously only wrapped the `button` div to wrap the
whole divs (which contain the image and the button) contained in each `item`, so the whole content is linked.
Adding `.item:hover .button { background-color:red}`, the buttons will be displayed 
in red when hovering an item container.

Note that there are different ways to display content next to each other - just
to mention one of them using `display:inline-block` - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9gq2mjaq/) - instead of floats. As
you'll notice, then also the buttons are displayed aligned next to each other.
It depends on the required layout (and maybe also on one's personal preferences)
which to choose.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to walk me through that! Very thorough explanation. I plan on going back to codeacademy to brush up on the things I rushed too fast through. Again thanks for your time.

Comment: @RoseHaggar Glad I was able to help you, and all the best for brushing up. If this answered your question, you can consider to accept this answer so the question will be marked as closed / solved. As I noticed you're maybe new to Stackoverflow and don't know how this works and why, just check http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work#answer-5235